# 2-Qubit Gate Teleportation with 1 Maximally Entangled State for Distributed Computation

Tags: teleportation, quantum-networks

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}$

I search for quantum circuits/protocols that enable distributed quantum computation of a 2-qubit gate using gate teleportation.

Let me explain the desired scenario with an example from here: [arXiv:2002.11808](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.11808) (Fig. 8).

[image: CNOT Gate Teleportation]

**SOURCE** and **DESTINATION** are 2 different parties that share a maximally entangled state ($\ket{\Phi^+}$).
Each party has a qubit, $\ket{\psi}$ and $\ket{\phi}$ respectively.
The depicted circuit computes $CNOT(\ket{\psi}\otimes\ket{\phi})$ using the maximally entangled state.
Note, that this circuit only uses 1 maximally entangled qubit pair and in the end **SOURCE** and **DESTINATION** both "keep their qubit".

I aim to generalize this circuit to compute an arbitrary 2-qubit gate or find similar circuits for other 2-qubit gates.
Other circuits should also have the 2 properties:

- use only 1 maximally entangled state
- both parties "keep their qubit"

---

#### My results so far

I already tried replacing the CNOT of **SOURCE** by an arbitrary 2-qubit gate:

[image: attempted arbitrary 2-qubit gate teleportation]

(First entangle $q_1$ and $q_2$, then attempted gate teleportation)

But I can't find any compensations (the part after measuring, terminology from [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1810)) that yield the desired result.

From looking at the resulting state it makes sense (to me) that this circuit doesn't work for arbitrary 2-qubit gates.
Assume $U$ is the matrix of a 2-qubit gate, then:

$\displaystyle U(\ket{\psi}\otimes\ket{\phi})=\left[\begin{matrix}\color{red}{u_{0}} & \color{green}{u_{1}} & \color{blue}{u_{2}} & \color{cyan}{u_{3}}\\\color{magenta}{u_{4}} & \color{yellow}{u_{5}} & \color{black}{u_{6}} & \color{gray}{u_{7}}\\\color{brown}{u_{8}} & \color{lime}{u_{9}} & \color{olive}{u_{10}} & \color{orange}{u_{11}}\\\color{pink}{u_{12}} & \color{purple}{u_{13}} & \color{teal}{u_{14}} & \color{violet}{u_{15}}\end{matrix}\right]\cdot\left[\begin{matrix}\psi_{0} \phi_{0}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{1}\\\psi_{1} \phi_{0}\\\psi_{1} \phi_{1}\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{red}{u_{0}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{green}{u_{1}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{blue}{u_{2}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{cyan}{u_{3}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{magenta}{u_{4}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{yellow}{u_{5}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{black}{u_{6}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{gray}{u_{7}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{brown}{u_{8}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{lime}{u_{9}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{olive}{u_{10}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{orange}{u_{11}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{pink}{u_{12}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{purple}{u_{13}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{teal}{u_{14}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{violet}{u_{15}}\end{matrix}\right]$

If I use $U$ in the circuit and measure qubits $q_1$ and $q_2$ we get the following states for $\ket{\psi}\otimes\ket{\phi}$ ($=q_0\otimes q_3$) written as $\ket{q_1q_2}\rightarrow \ket{\psi\phi}$:

$$\displaystyle \ket{00}\rightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{red}{u_{0}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{green}{u_{1}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{blue}{u_{2}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{cyan}{u_{3}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{green}{u_{1}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{red}{u_{0}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{cyan}{u_{3}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{blue}{u_{2}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{brown}{u_{8}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{lime}{u_{9}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{olive}{u_{10}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{orange}{u_{11}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{lime}{u_{9}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{brown}{u_{8}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{orange}{u_{11}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{olive}{u_{10}}\end{matrix}\right]$$

$$\displaystyle \ket{01}\rightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{red}{u_{0}} - \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{green}{u_{1}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{blue}{u_{2}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{cyan}{u_{3}}\\- \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{green}{u_{1}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{red}{u_{0}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{cyan}{u_{3}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{blue}{u_{2}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{brown}{u_{8}} - \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{lime}{u_{9}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{olive}{u_{10}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{orange}{u_{11}}\\- \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{lime}{u_{9}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{brown}{u_{8}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{orange}{u_{11}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{olive}{u_{10}}\end{matrix}\right]$$

$$\displaystyle \ket{10}\rightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{magenta}{u_{4}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{yellow}{u_{5}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{black}{u_{6}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{gray}{u_{7}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{yellow}{u_{5}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{magenta}{u_{4}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{gray}{u_{7}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{black}{u_{6}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{pink}{u_{12}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{purple}{u_{13}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{teal}{u_{14}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{violet}{u_{15}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{purple}{u_{13}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{pink}{u_{12}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{violet}{u_{15}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{teal}{u_{14}}\end{matrix}\right]$$

$$\displaystyle \ket{11}\rightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{magenta}{u_{4}} - \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{yellow}{u_{5}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{black}{u_{6}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{gray}{u_{7}}\\- \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{yellow}{u_{5}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{magenta}{u_{4}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{gray}{u_{7}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{black}{u_{6}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{pink}{u_{12}} - \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{purple}{u_{13}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{teal}{u_{14}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{violet}{u_{15}}\\- \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{purple}{u_{13}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{pink}{u_{12}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{violet}{u_{15}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{teal}{u_{14}}\end{matrix}\right]$$

Since $\ket{\psi\phi}$ is always missing some $u_x$ I don't see how this circuit could be used to compute arbitrary 2-qubit gates.

---

If I change the circuit to measure qubits $q_2$ and $q_3$:

[image: 2-qubit gate teleportation]

the state $\ket{q_0q_1}$ contains all $u_x$:

$$\displaystyle \ket{00}\rightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{red}{u_{0}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{green}{u_{1}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{blue}{u_{2}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{cyan}{u_{3}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{magenta}{u_{4}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{yellow}{u_{5}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{black}{u_{6}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{gray}{u_{7}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{brown}{u_{8}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{lime}{u_{9}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{olive}{u_{10}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{orange}{u_{11}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{pink}{u_{12}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{purple}{u_{13}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{teal}{u_{14}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{violet}{u_{15}}\end{matrix}\right]$$

$$\displaystyle \ket{01}\rightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{green}{u_{1}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{red}{u_{0}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{cyan}{u_{3}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{blue}{u_{2}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{yellow}{u_{5}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{magenta}{u_{4}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{gray}{u_{7}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{black}{u_{6}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{lime}{u_{9}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{brown}{u_{8}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{orange}{u_{11}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{olive}{u_{10}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{purple}{u_{13}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{pink}{u_{12}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{violet}{u_{15}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{teal}{u_{14}}\end{matrix}\right]$$

$$\displaystyle \ket{10}\rightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{red}{u_{0}} - \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{green}{u_{1}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{blue}{u_{2}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{cyan}{u_{3}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{magenta}{u_{4}} - \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{yellow}{u_{5}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{black}{u_{6}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{gray}{u_{7}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{brown}{u_{8}} - \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{lime}{u_{9}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{olive}{u_{10}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{orange}{u_{11}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{pink}{u_{12}} - \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{purple}{u_{13}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{teal}{u_{14}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{violet}{u_{15}}\end{matrix}\right]$$

$$\displaystyle \ket{11}\rightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}- \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{green}{u_{1}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{red}{u_{0}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{cyan}{u_{3}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{blue}{u_{2}}\\- \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{yellow}{u_{5}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{magenta}{u_{4}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{gray}{u_{7}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{black}{u_{6}}\\- \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{lime}{u_{9}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{brown}{u_{8}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{orange}{u_{11}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{olive}{u_{10}}\\- \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{purple}{u_{13}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{pink}{u_{12}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{violet}{u_{15}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{teal}{u_{14}}\end{matrix}\right]$$

but I lose the property that both parties "keep their qubit".

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}$

This paper: [arXiv:quant-ph/0005101](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0005101) shows how a circuit, closely related to the CNOT teleportation from the question, can be generalized to arbitrary **controlled** 2-qubit gates.

[image: CNOT gate teleportation]

This circuit again assumes a maximally entangled state ($\ket{\Phi^+}$) shared between the 2 qubits in the middle, where qubit $1$ belongs to $A$ and qubit $2$ belongs to $B$.
The dashed vertical lines represent classical communication.

To generalize this circuit to arbitrary controlled 2-qubit gates, the CNOT of the **RECEIVER** ($B$) is replaced by $U$:

[image: arbitrary controlled 2-qubit gate teleportation]

(First entangle qubits $q_1$ and $q_2$ then perform the teleportation. Gates cut by the red line are realized via measurements and classical communication.)

In this generalization we assume $U$ to be an arbitrary **controlled** gate:

$$\displaystyle U(\ket{\psi}\otimes\ket{\phi})=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & \color{red}{u_{0}} & \color{green}{u_{1}}\\0 & 0 & \color{blue}{u_{2}} & \color{cyan}{u_{3}}\end{matrix}\right]\cdot\left[\begin{matrix}\psi_{0} \phi_{0}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{1}\\\psi_{1} \phi_{0}\\\psi_{1} \phi_{1}\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}\psi_{0} \phi_{0}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{1}\\\psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{red}{u_{0}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{green}{u_{1}}\\\psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{blue}{u_{2}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{cyan}{u_{3}}\end{matrix}\right]$$

---

**Remark:**

I didn't really look into it, but, to me, this circuit doesn't seem to work for arbitrary 2-qubit gates, i.e.

$$\displaystyle U(\ket{\psi}\otimes\ket{\phi})=\left[\begin{matrix}\color{red}{u_{0}} & \color{green}{u_{1}} & \color{blue}{u_{2}} & \color{cyan}{u_{3}}\\\color{magenta}{u_{4}} & \color{yellow}{u_{5}} & \color{black}{u_{6}} & \color{gray}{u_{7}}\\\color{brown}{u_{8}} & \color{lime}{u_{9}} & \color{olive}{u_{10}} & \color{orange}{u_{11}}\\\color{pink}{u_{12}} & \color{purple}{u_{13}} & \color{teal}{u_{14}} & \color{violet}{u_{15}}\end{matrix}\right]\cdot\left[\begin{matrix}\psi_{0} \phi_{0}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{1}\\\psi_{1} \phi_{0}\\\psi_{1} \phi_{1}\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{red}{u_{0}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{green}{u_{1}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{blue}{u_{2}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{cyan}{u_{3}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{magenta}{u_{4}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{yellow}{u_{5}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{black}{u_{6}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{gray}{u_{7}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{brown}{u_{8}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{lime}{u_{9}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{olive}{u_{10}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{orange}{u_{11}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{pink}{u_{12}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{purple}{u_{13}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{teal}{u_{14}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{violet}{u_{15}}\end{matrix}\right]$$

Here are the resulting states of the circuit with arbitrary $U$ and **without compensations** (gates cut by the dashed red line) written as $\ket{q_1q_2}\rightarrow\ket{\psi\phi}$:

$$\displaystyle \ket{00}\rightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{red}{u_{0}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{brown}{u_{8}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{green}{u_{1}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{lime}{u_{9}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{pink}{u_{12}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{magenta}{u_{4}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{purple}{u_{13}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{yellow}{u_{5}}\\\psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{olive}{u_{10}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{blue}{u_{2}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{orange}{u_{11}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{cyan}{u_{3}}\\\psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{teal}{u_{14}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{black}{u_{6}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{violet}{u_{15}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{gray}{u_{7}}\end{matrix}\right]$$

$$\displaystyle \ket{01}\rightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{red}{u_{0}} - \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{brown}{u_{8}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{green}{u_{1}} - \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{lime}{u_{9}}\\- \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{pink}{u_{12}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{magenta}{u_{4}} - \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{purple}{u_{13}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{yellow}{u_{5}}\\- \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{olive}{u_{10}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{blue}{u_{2}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{orange}{u_{11}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{cyan}{u_{3}}\\- \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{teal}{u_{14}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{black}{u_{6}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{violet}{u_{15}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{gray}{u_{7}}\end{matrix}\right]$$

$$\displaystyle \ket{10}\rightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{olive}{u_{10}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{blue}{u_{2}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{orange}{u_{11}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{cyan}{u_{3}}\\\psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{teal}{u_{14}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{black}{u_{6}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{violet}{u_{15}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{gray}{u_{7}}\\\psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{red}{u_{0}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{brown}{u_{8}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{green}{u_{1}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{lime}{u_{9}}\\\psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{pink}{u_{12}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{magenta}{u_{4}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{purple}{u_{13}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{yellow}{u_{5}}\end{matrix}\right]$$

$$\displaystyle \ket{11}\rightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}- \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{olive}{u_{10}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{blue}{u_{2}} - \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{orange}{u_{11}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{cyan}{u_{3}}\\- \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{teal}{u_{14}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{0} \color{black}{u_{6}} - \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{violet}{u_{15}} + \psi_{0} \phi_{1} \color{gray}{u_{7}}\\\psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{red}{u_{0}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{brown}{u_{8}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{green}{u_{1}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{lime}{u_{9}}\\- \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{pink}{u_{12}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{0} \color{magenta}{u_{4}} - \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{purple}{u_{13}} + \psi_{1} \phi_{1} \color{yellow}{u_{5}}\end{matrix}\right]$$

However, the paper ([arXiv:quant-ph/0005101](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0005101)) also addresses the issue of arbitrary 2-qubit gates:

> General single-bit rotations together with a CNOT gate are sufficient to implement any multi-qubit unitary transformation. This implies that the resource requirements for the implementation of a CNOT gate are a limiting factor in the construction of general unitary transformations in a distributed
> quantum computer.

Comment: This protocol is more general. Notice though that the Destination has to wait for the source to perform its part (classical communication as well). I recently started designing more general protocols that don't feature this drawback. Stay tuned!